# How to edit datagrid i.e populated using Linq to entities query?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, datagrid, linq-to-entities

I have used linq to entities for making a join of multiple tables, the result of(Linq to entity query) which i have bound to datagrid. As excepted data is populated in datagrid but it is not editable. So how i can make this datagrid editable so i can edit and update data?

My code is as follows:

```
public static void displaydata()
    {
      //  MessageBox.Show("Hiii");

        rDatabaseEntities rde = new rDatabaseEntities();

        var displayquery = from del in rde.Deliveries
                           join tr in rde.Transporters on del.TransporterID equals tr.TransporterID
                           join it in rde.Items on del.ItemID equals it.ItemID
                           join pu in rde.Pumps on del.PumpID equals pu.PumpID
                           join pa in rde.Parties on del.PartyID equals pa.PartyID
                           join src in rde.Sources on del.SourceID equals src.SourceID
                           join dest in rde.Destinations on del.DestinationID equals dest.DestinationID

                           select new
                           {
                               del.TruckNo,
                               del.Weight,
                               del.LR_No,
                               del.cashAdv,
                               del.dieselAdv,
                               del.Dcpino,
                               del.Bal,
                               del.Freight,
                               del.Remarks,
                               tr.transporterName,
                               it.itemName,
                               pu.pumpName,
                               pa.partyName,
                               dest.destinationName

                           };
        var display = displayquery.ToList();

        displaygrid.ItemsSource = display;

    }
```

Your help would be highly appreciated.